# Django elastic search dsl-drf

Tags: django, elasticsearch

```
RequestError at /elastic-producthub/category-search
RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [division_id] in order to sort on')
```

this is the error am getting from django elastic search dsl .Actually I have a model called category and have a foreign key called division. Here, I want to perform a search query on category with division name.

Comment: Please add the code with which you import your model data into Elastic, and also the elastic schema. If you need help, you need to provide sufficient information to debug. It is not sufficient to know what you want to happen, we also require to know what you actually did.

Comment: its an ecommerce application and I need an search query that works with parent and child models .please help me!

Comment: Can you tries to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?